# Blazor GenericEditForm

Tags: generics, blazor, blazor-editform

i dont know if this is relevant to write here.

I want to create a GenericEditForm.razor which can be used on multiple pages.

I currently have made the GenericEditForm component so that it takes a @typeparam TModel which can be different kinds of Models.
I also give it a json config, where i have specified something i call "render definitions".
There is a json config for each of my possible models that i would want to create a GenericEditForm for.
In the json config i have a list of ojbects times the properties of my model

My problem is that i cant find a way to use the @bind-value og @bind to bind the different form controls to the models properties, given that the GenericEditForm components only knows the model and its properties at runtime.

Any ideas of how to fix this, using data binding.

JSON CONFIG:

```
{
  "CreateTitle": "Create new committee",
  "Fields": [
    {
      "ModelPropName": "Department",
      "DisplayName": "Department",
      "FormControlType": "InputSelect",
      "Items": [
        "Afdeling A",
        "Afdeling B",
        "Afdeling C"
      ],
      "Rules": {
        "Mandatory": true,
        "Regex": "[a-zA-Z0-9.,_ åæøÅÆØ-]{0,100}"
      }
    },
    {
      "ModelPropName": "CommitteeName",
      "DisplayName": "Committee name",
      "FormControlType": "InputText",
      "Rules": {
        "Mandatory": true,
        "regex": "[a-zA-Z0-9.,_ åæøÅÆØ-]{0,100}"
      }
    },
    {
      "ModelPropName": "Status",
      "DisplayName": "Status",
      "FormControlType": "InputSelect",
      "Items": [
        "Status 1",
        "Status 2"
      ],
      "Rules": {
        "Mandatory": true,
        "regex": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

GenericEditForm:

```
 @foreach (var field in FormControlConfig.Fields)
                        {
                            var propertyName = field.ModelPropName;
                            var propertyInfo = typeof(TItem).GetProperty(propertyName);
                            var propertyValue = GetPropertyValue(propertyInfo);
                            switch (field.FormControlType)
                            {
                                case "InputText":
                                    <EditFormControlWrapper FieldName="@field.DisplayName" IsRequired="@field.Rules.Mandatory">
                                        <div class="col-xs-17 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
                                            <input type="text"
                                   spellcheck="true"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   id="@propertyName"
                                   value="@propertyValue"
                                   @oninput="e => SetValue(e.Value, propertyInfo)">
                                        </div>
                                    </EditFormControlWrapper>
                                    break;
                                case "InputSelect":
                                    @if (field.DisplayName == "Status")
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    <EditFormControlWrapper FieldName="@field.DisplayName" IsRequired="@field.Rules.Mandatory" isSelect="true">
                                        <div class="col-xs-17 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11 select">
                                            <select class="form-control"
                                    id="@propertyName"
                                    value="@propertyValue"
                                    @oninput="e => SetValue(e.Value, propertyInfo)">
                                                <option value="" />
                                                @foreach (var item in field.Items)
                                                {
                                                    <option value="@item">@item</option>
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </EditFormControlWrapper>
                                    break;
                                case "InputTextArea":
                                    <EditFormControlWrapper FieldName="@field.DisplayName" IsRequired="@field.Rules.Mandatory">
                                        <div class="col-xs-17 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
                                            <textarea cols="20"
                                      rows="4"
                                      type="text"
                                      spellcheck="true"
                                      class="form-control"
                                      id="@propertyName"
                                      value="@propertyValue"
                                      @oninput="e => SetValue(e.Value, propertyInfo)" />
                                        </div>
                                    </EditFormControlWrapper>
                                    break;
                                case "InputDate":
                                    <EditFormControlWrapper FieldName="@field.DisplayName" IsRequired="@field.Rules.Mandatory">
                                        <div class="col-xs-17 col-sm-7 col-md-10 col-lg-3">
                                            <input type="date"
                                   class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker"
                                   value="@Convert.ToString(propertyValue)"
                                   @oninput="e => SetValue(DateTime.Parse(e.Value.ToString()), propertyInfo)" />
                                        </div>
                                    </EditFormControlWrapper>
                                    break;
                                case "InputTime":
                                    var startName = "MeetingTimeStart";
                                    var endName = "MeetingTimeEnd";
                                    var propertyInfoStart = typeof(TItem).GetProperty(startName);
                                    var propertyInfoEnd = typeof(TItem).GetProperty(endName);
                                    var startValue = GetPropertyValue(propertyInfoStart);
                                    var endValue = GetPropertyValue(propertyInfoEnd);

                                    <EditFormControlWrapper FieldName="@field.DisplayName" IsRequired="@field.Rules.Mandatory">
                                        <div class="col-xs-17 col-sm-7 col-md-10 col-lg-2 select">
                                            <select class="form-control"
                                    min="09:00" max="18:00"
                                    size="1"
                                    id="@startName"
                                    value="@Convert.ToString(startValue)"
                                    @oninput="e => SetValue(TimeSpan.Parse(e.Value.ToString()), propertyInfoStart)">
                                                @for (int hour = 9; hour <= 18; hour++)
                                                {
                                                    @for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute += 15)
                                                    {
                                                        var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(hour, minute, 0);
                                                        var timeString = timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
                                                        <option value="@timeSpan">@timeString</option>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-0">
                                            <label class="control-label">
                                                :
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-17 col-sm-7 col-md-10 col-lg-2 select">
                                            <select class="form-control"
                                    min="09:00" max="18:00"
                                    size="1"
                                    id="@endName"
                                    value="@Convert.ToString(endValue)"
                                    @oninput="e => SetValue(TimeSpan.Parse(e.Value.ToString()), propertyInfoEnd)">
                                                @for (int hour = 9; hour <= 18; hour++)
                                                {
                                                    @for (int minute = 0; minute < 60; minute += 15)
                                                    {
                                                        var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(hour, minute, 0);
                                                        var timeString = timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
                                                        <option value="@timeSpan">@timeString</option>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </EditFormControlWrapper>
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
    
@code {
 [Parameter]
    public ProfileFormControlConfigModel FormControlConfig { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public object? EditObject { get; set; }

    public TItem CreateModel;

    public bool hasStatusField = false;

    public bool isActive = false;

    public Field field;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            CreateModel = Activator.CreateInstance<TItem>();

            var result = CreateModel.GetType().GetProperty("Status");

        if (result != null) { hasStatusField = true; }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            // Handle ArgumentNullException related to the GetProperty() method
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Property name is null.");
        }
        catch (AmbiguousMatchException ex)
        {
            // Handle AmbiguousMatchException related to the GetProperty() method
            Console.WriteLine("Error: More than one property with the specified name found.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle any other exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
 public void SetValue(object value, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        Type propType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        propertyInfo.SetValue(CreateModel, value);
    }

    private object GetPropertyValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        Type propType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

        object propertyValue;

        propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(CreateModel);
        
        return propertyValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to build your component with RenderTreeBuilder in BuildRenderTree event to access all component feature in code.

Comment: At first the generic form concept seems like an obvious way to go. Yet when you search for how other people have implemented it you draw a bit of a blank.  Before you plough on consider why the Internet is not awash with examples.  The answer is it's a Holy Grail project. Your config file will keep on  growing in complexity as you code mor options.  In the end it will be more complex that building the form manually.

Comment: Thanks for the response
 @MrCakaShaunCurtis


I have edited the post to a solution that worked for me. If u would like to look at the solution and if u have some response i would appreciate it.

Is the solution sufficient enough, and is it good practice the way i made it work ?

Comment: the above comment is also for u @mRizvandi :)

Comment: Writing such a component is a lot of work, which is why you only find them in paid component suites. The ones we build ourselves are too dirty to publish. You can use reflection to find all properties in a type and emit fields. But then you also need to add extra information for validation, formatting, labels, comments, etc. Never mind related fields, eg linked dropdowns.  Reflection is expensive so you need to *cache* the properties, definitions etc.

Comment: You can simplify your code a lot by using components though. For example, extract the code that generates each type of field into its own component.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos good idea. Didnt think about that, was to dived into the "i want to use @bind-value" approach.

Comment: @FoodCoderMan - I'm away at the moment, but I'll put dome resources together for you this weekend.  There's some different approaches that you can take to the problem to minimize your code.

Comment: I check out the comments and I think you have to use RenderTreeBuilder to do anything... I think you have to generate generic list of object for all properties in json, remove EditForm and bind each input component to cell of list and validate by your custom validation...